# Visual Studio 2013 converted an entire JS code file to hex and binary

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, hex

**data.js**

[image]

I started VS2013 and all of a sudden, an entire file (which existed purely of JS code since it's a Windows Store JS App) got converted into what you see above. If I highlight some of the hex code, the appropriate "dots" get highlighted too and vice versa.

Is there any way at all to retrieve my code?

Comment: I suspect the hex dump you're showing isn't the actual file, given the errors. The hex dump shows something consisting entirely of zeros, but the errors indicate actual code somewhere.

Comment: could be, but when I load the data.js file from the solution explorer, it comes straight to this file. It doesn't even preview the file when I single click it the way it previews other files.

Comment: And the errors are referring to the base.js file.

Comment: @ DemCodeLines: Ah. Well, in that case, I'm sorry to say that based on what you've shown in that screenshot, you're SOL. Time to go to backups, check out the earlier version from source control, etc. Something (I very much doubt it was VS.Net 2013) has overwritten that file with a bunch of zeros.

Comment: This just happaned to me, The last program interacting with the file was Visual studio 2013 as well. The file was a .vash-file (javascript template).

Comment: It happened to me also and Visual Studio was the last program the file interacted with. This is very bad, i have lose hours of work ;(